# Format an SQL statement for currency

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, currency

```
$salaryquery = "
    SELECT
      salary.salary
    FROM grp19.salary
      INNER JOIN grp19.player
        ON (salary.pid = player.pid)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN grp19.custom_database
        ON (player.pid = custom_database.pid)
          AND custom_database.username = $2
    WHERE player.pid = $1
";

$result = pg_prepare($conn, "salary_print", $salaryquery);
$result = pg_execute($conn, "salary_print", array($playerid, $_SESSION['user']));

    //print team
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<b>Salary: </b>"; 

    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
        foreach ($row as $data){
            echo"$data";
            echo " ";
        }
    }
```

If I am trying to print `$data` in currency format. Is there some simple way to do this?

The select statement is using a player's id to get their salary based on a salary table and a player table from a database...

It also uses a specific database for each user. I'm mainly concerned if there is a way I can print the returned value in a currency format...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format numbers. A currency symbol, if you need one, can just be echoed before.

```
echo number_format($data, 2, '.', ',');
```